# Pod limit on Node - AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

On AWS EKS
I'm adding deployment with 17 replicas (requesting and limiting 64Mi memory) to a small cluster with 2 nodes type t3.small.

Counting with kube-system pods, total running pods per node is 11 and 1 is left pending, i.e.:

Node #1: 
aws-node-1
coredns-5-1as3
coredns-5-2das
kube-proxy-1
+7 app pod replicas       

Node #2:
aws-node-1
kube-proxy-1
+9 app pod replicas

I understand that t3.small is a very small instance. I'm only trying to understand what is limiting me here. Memory request is not it, I'm way below the available resources.

I found that there is IP addresses limit per node depending on instance type.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html?shortFooter=true#AvailableIpPerENI .
I didn't find any other documentation saying explicitly that this is limiting pod creation, but I'm assuming it does.
Based on the table, t3.small can have 12 IPv4 addresses. If this is the case and this is limiting factor, since I have 11 pods, where did 1 missing IPv4 address go?

Comment: After investigation you have applied standard [amazon-vpc-cni-k8s plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html) so please visit aws on [github](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/176) on-line resources, discussion about pros and cons [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/networking-foundation-eks-aws-cni-calico/) and [here](https://medium.com/codeops/installing-weave-cni-on-aws-eks-51c2e6b7abc8) to find out how to disable aws cni on aws and install overlay network like [calico](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html)

Comment: did you found the solution? how to increase the limit or completely disable it?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The real maximum number of pods per EKS instance are actually listed in [this document](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt).

For t3.small instances, it is 11 pods per instance. That is, you can have a maximum number of 22 pods in your cluster. 6 of these pods are system pods, so there remains a maximum of 16 workload pods.

You're trying to run 17 workload pods, so it's one too much. I guess 16 of these pods have been scheduled and 1 is left pending.

---

The [formula](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt) for defining the maximum number of pods per instance is as follows:

```
N * (M-1) + 2
```

Where:

- N is the number of Elastic Network Interfaces (ENI) of the instance type
- M is the number of IP addresses of a single ENI

So, for t3.small, this calculation is `3 * (4-1) + 2 = 11`.

Values for `N` and `M` for each instance type in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI).

Comment: yeah, I was looking for pod limit, that's why I made 17 :) . That document looks like it, why it is not in official documentation... Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Yeah, it should be in the documentation. The document is worth bookmarking, because if you work with EKS, you have to refer to it a lot :)

Comment: Running "kubectl describe node <node-internal-dns-name>" for each of your nodes will reveal the max number of pods for that node under the "Capacity/pods" section.

Comment: Could it be increased ?

Comment: It could probably be increased by adding ENIs to the EC2 instances.

Comment: Hi @weibeld. I found your answer while searching for my question regarding pod-on-node issue of EKS here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68532574/2576485

May you also help me on that question if possible? Many thanks!

Answer (score 28):

For anyone who runs across this when searching google.  Be advised that as of August 2021 its now possible to increase the max pods on a node using the latest AWS CNI plugin as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-vpc-cni-increases-pods-per-node-limits/).

Using the basic configuration explained there a t3.medium node went from a max of 17 pods to a max of 110 which is more then adequate for what I was trying to do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the answer. You can also follow the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-increase-ip-addresses.html

Answer (score 9):

This is why we stopped using `EKS` in favor of a KOPS deployed self-managed cluster.
IMO `EKS` which employs the `aws-cni` causes too many constraints, it actually goes against one of the major benefits of using Kubernetes, efficient use of available resources.
`EKS` moves the system constraint away from `CPU / memory` usage into the realm of network IP limitations.

Kubernetes was designed to provide high density, manage resources efficiently. Not quite so with `EKS’s` version, since a node could be idle, with almost its entire memory available and yet the cluster will be unable to schedule pods on an otherwise low utilized node if `pods > (N * (M-1) + 2)`.

One could be tempted to employ another `CNI` such as `Calico`, however would be limited to worker nodes since access to master nodes is forbidden.  This causes the cluster to have two networks and problems will arise when trying to access `K8s API`, or working with Admissions Controllers.

It really does depend on workflow requirements, for us, high pod density, efficient use of resources, and having complete control of the cluster is paramount.

Answer (score 4):

connect to you EKS node

run this

```
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh clusterName --use-max-pods false  --kubelet-extra-args '--max-pods=50'
```

ignore nvidia-smi not found the output

whole script location https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/bootstrap.sh

Comment: can you please provide a reference to run this script using terraform in launch template...it will help me...

Comment: this command will work also aws-vpc-cni ? or its work only for calico ?

Comment: For terraform, you can run this script in the User-Data script.

Answer (score 2):

EKS allows to increase max number of pods per node but this can be done only with Nitro instances. check the list [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances)

- Make sure you have VPC CNI 1.9+
- Enable Prefix delegation for VPC_CNI plugin

  `kubectl set env daemonset aws-node -n kube-system ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION=true`
- If you are using `self managed` node group, make sure to pass the following in `BootstrapArguments`
  `--use-max-pods false --kubelet-extra-args '--max-pods=110'`

  - or you could create the node group using `eksctl` using
    `eksctl create nodegroup --cluster my-cluster --managed=false --max-pods-per-node 110`
- If you are using `managed` node group with a specified AMI, it has `bootstrap.sh` so you could modify `user_data` to do something like this
  `/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh my-cluster \ --use-max-pods false \ --kubelet-extra-args '--max-pods=110'`

  - Or simply using `eksctl` by running

  `eksctl create nodegroup --cluster my-cluster --max-pods-per-node 110`

For more details, check AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-increase-ip-addresses.html