# Kubernetes - AutoScaling doesn't increase the number of nodes when pod limit has reached

Tags: kubernetes

Update: found that instances has a limit to number of [pods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57971006/8445363).

Does that mean that auto-scaling group won't increase the node count unless the CPU or memory resources hit that limit?

I'm running `t3.medium` instance and looking at the nodes describe command output it hasn't used 100% of resources.  But I get the error `0/1 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods.`.

Another thing is I have auto scaling configured for cluster node group, and the max size is 2 but second node hasn't spawn yet which means there is still resources right?

```
  scaling_config {
    desired_size  = 1
    max_size      = 2
    min_size      = 1
  }
```

Can someone explain why it can't run new pod and what's blocking it?

`kubectl get po -A`:

```
NAMESPACE        NAME                                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default          alertmanager-prometheus-prometheus-oper-alertmanager-0          2/2     Running   0          3h34m
default          mongo-express-5b8b8989c8-b7qq8                                  1/1     Running   0          3h33m
default          mongodb-0                                                       1/1     Running   0          3h37m
default          mongodb-1                                                       1/1     Running   0          3h36m
default          mongodb-arbiter-0                                               1/1     Running   0          3h36m
default          mongodb-exporter-prometheus-mongodb-exporter-786999d67c-c586f   1/1     Running   0          123m
default          nginx-ingress-controller-868b5465b4-8klbr                       1/1     Running   0          3h45m
default          nginx-ingress-default-backend-7c868597f4-n85s8                  1/1     Running   0          3h45m
default          prometheus-grafana-67596ff846-nkssr                             2/2     Running   0          3h35m
default          prometheus-kube-state-metrics-c65b87574-g6pt7                   1/1     Running   0          3h35m
default          prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-kl5b2                       1/1     Running   0          3h35m
default          prometheus-prometheus-oper-operator-5ff8fbd5fb-fzgvf            2/2     Running   0          3h35m
default          prometheus-prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus-0              3/3     Running   1          3h34m
kube-system      aws-node-7t29d                                                  1/1     Running   0          5h58m
kube-system      coredns-6b4cdc67b4-7mnjh                                        1/1     Running   0          6h2m
kube-system      coredns-6b4cdc67b4-7px74                                        1/1     Running   0          6h2m
kube-system      kube-proxy-dl2dr                                                1/1     Running   0          5h58m
test-db-dev   db01-0                                                          0/1     Pending   0          11m


`kubectl describe node`:

    Name:               ip-10-0-0-250.ap-south-1.compute.internal
    Roles:              <none>
    Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.medium
                        beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND
                        eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=test_nodes-dev
                        eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-0ad87e82a7f1e7f4b
                        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-south-1
                        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-south-1b
                        kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-0-250.ap-south-1.compute.internal
                        kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.medium
                        topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-south-1
                        topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-south-1b
    Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                        volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
    CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 09 Dec 2020 03:43:22 -0500
    Taints:             <none>
    Unschedulable:      false
    Lease:
      HolderIdentity:  ip-10-0-0-250.ap-south-1.compute.internal
      AcquireTime:     <unset>
      RenewTime:       Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:39:11 -0500
    Conditions:
      Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
      ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
      MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:39:04 -0500   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 03:43:22 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
      DiskPressure     False   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:39:04 -0500   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 03:43:22 -0500   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
      PIDPressure      False   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:39:04 -0500   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 03:43:22 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
      Ready            True    Wed, 09 Dec 2020 09:39:04 -0500   Wed, 09 Dec 2020 03:43:42 -0500   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
    Addresses:
      InternalIP:   10.0.0.250
      Hostname:     ip-10-0-0-250.ap-south-1.compute.internal
      InternalDNS:  ip-10-0-0-250.ap-south-1.compute.internal
    Capacity:
      attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
      cpu:                         2
      ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
      hugepages-1Gi:               0
      hugepages-2Mi:               0
      memory:                      3977908Ki
      pods:                        17
    Allocatable:
      attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
      cpu:                         1930m
      ephemeral-storage:           18242267924
      hugepages-1Gi:               0
      hugepages-2Mi:               0
      memory:                      3422900Ki
      pods:                        17
    System Info:
      Machine ID:                 ec2474d1824a7ec75cfb9c1704c92d34
      System UUID:                EC2474D1-824A-7EC7-5CFB-9C1704C92D34
      Boot ID:                    3ddcd32a-8b7a-4a21-b41b-37a51686ca67
      Kernel Version:             4.14.203-156.332.amzn2.x86_64
      OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
      Operating System:           linux
      Architecture:               amd64
      Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.6
      Kubelet Version:            v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
      Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
    ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-south-1b/i-047e645215dc3c7e1
    Non-terminated Pods:          (17 in total)
      Namespace                   Name                                                             CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
      ---------                   ----                                                             ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
      default                     alertmanager-prometheus-prometheus-oper-alertmanager-0           100m (5%)     100m (5%)   225Mi (6%)       25Mi (0%)      3h32m
      default                     mongo-express-5b8b8989c8-b7qq8                                   0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h31m
      default                     mongodb-0                                                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h34m
      default                     mongodb-1                                                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h34m
      default                     mongodb-arbiter-0                                                0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h34m
      default                     mongodb-exporter-prometheus-mongodb-exporter-786999d67c-c586f    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         121m
      default                     nginx-ingress-controller-868b5465b4-8klbr                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h43m
      default                     nginx-ingress-default-backend-7c868597f4-n85s8                   0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h43m
      default                     prometheus-grafana-67596ff846-nkssr                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h32m
      default                     prometheus-kube-state-metrics-c65b87574-g6pt7                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h32m
      default                     prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-kl5b2                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h32m
      default                     prometheus-prometheus-oper-operator-5ff8fbd5fb-fzgvf             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3h32m
      default                     prometheus-prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus-0               200m (10%)    200m (10%)  50Mi (1%)        50Mi (1%)      3h32m
      kube-system                 aws-node-7t29d                                                   10m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5h55m
      kube-system                 coredns-6b4cdc67b4-7mnjh                                         100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (2%)        170Mi (5%)     6h
      kube-system                 coredns-6b4cdc67b4-7px74                                         100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (2%)        170Mi (5%)     6h
      kube-system                 kube-proxy-dl2dr                                                 100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5h55m
    Allocated resources:
      (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
      Resource                    Requests     Limits
      --------                    --------     ------
      cpu                         610m (31%)   300m (15%)
      memory                      415Mi (12%)  415Mi (12%)
      ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)       0 (0%)
      hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)       0 (0%)
      hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)       0 (0%)
      attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0            0
    Events:                       <none>
```

Comment: You can try this to increase pod limit https://medium.com/@swazza85/dealing-with-pod-density-limitations-on-eks-worker-nodes-137a12c8b218

Comment: any idea how to resize cluster nodes? I have a min 1 and max of 2. I need to increase it without deleting the cluster.