# Kubenetes AWS EKS are assigning all pods into only one node while leaving the other node free

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl, external-dns

**Background:**

I have an EKS cluster with 2 nodes (t3.small).
The cluster is having several pods including:

- 1 pod for web frontend
- 1 pod for backend
- AWS ALB controller
- External DNS

**Current behavior:**

- All backend and web frontend pods + other AWS ALB pods (cert-manager, cert-manager-cainjector, cert-manager-webhook, app-backend-deployment, app-frontend-deployment, external-dns, aws-load-balancer-controller, etc. - 11 pods in total) are all allocated into 1 single node.
- The other node is only running 2 pods (aws-node & kube-proxy), meaning no application nodes are assigned to.
- **Consequence:** One node is frequently down or goes to non-ready status due to CPU/memory shortage, while the other is completely free and not being used.

**Desired behavior (or my opinionated expected behavior):** The pods should be allocated more equally.

Am I missing anything in the configuration?

Comment: check the nodes; are both flagged to permit scheduling?  Are both nodes flagged as Ready when you check with `kubectl get nodes` ?  Are you sure your taints + tolerations are correct in your deployment manifests, and that you're not accidentally excluding a node that way?

Comment: Good pointers @mcfinnigan

Comment: Thanks @mcfinnigan for your suggestions. I checked them and don't see the problem with my config:
- `kubectl get nodes` returns both nodes in ready status
- I check each node via `kubectl describe node <node>` and `Taints: <none>, Unschedulable: false`. `Allocatable pods` on each node is 11.
- I experimentally scale the replicate of `app-web` and `app-backend` deployments to be 2 pods for each. The new pods are allocated in the free node. That means other node is running well.

Maybe the External DNS and AWS ALB Ingress Controller have rules to only install in 1 single node?